# Revealing cards sorcery

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The [Pieces of the Puzzle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPieces%20of%20the%20Puzzle%5d) MTG card states:

> Reveal the top five cards of your library. Put up to two instant and/or sorcery cards from among them into your hand and the rest into your graveyard.

**My question is**: does it mean a player should show which cards he revealed from the library or not? Should the player show which cards he puts into his hand or not? If not how to check that player plays honestly?

Comment: The terminology you are thinking of is "look at" instead of "reveal". See Ancient Stirrings for an example. It has you look at the top 5 cards of your library, so only you get to see them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you not only need to show all five cards, you need to show which of those you picked.

No action is taken in secret; all players are to be made aware of all actions taken and what they effect. And since the cards are revealed when you pick them, they get to know not just what card you picked, but it's name as well.

> 701.14a To reveal a card, **show that card to all players** for a brief time. If an effect causes a card to be revealed, **it remains revealed for as long as necessary to complete the parts of the effect that card is relevant to**. If the cost to cast a spell or activate an ability includes revealing a card, the card remains revealed from the time the spell or ability is announced until the time it leaves the stack.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Okay, so the term "reveal" means, that this card should be shown to all players?

Comment: Yes, that's what reveal means. "*701.14a To reveal a card, show that card to all players for a brief time. [...]*"

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, "revealing" cards means to show it to all players.**

The library is a so-called "hidden zone", meaning the cards in it are not visible to everyone.

> 400.2. Public zones are zones in which all players can see the cards’ faces, except for those cards that some rule or effect specifically allow to be face down. Graveyard, battlefield, stack, exile, ante, and command are public zones. Hidden zones are zones in which not all players can be expected to see the cards’ faces. Library and hand are hidden zones, even if all the cards in one such zone happen to be revealed.

It requires a special effect to look at some or all of the cards in a hidden zone. As the first sentence states, you have to reveal the top 5 cards before you choose some of them to put in your hand. You have to show all the players which cards you chose to put in your hand.

Rules for revealing a card:

> 701.14a To reveal a card, show that card to all players for a brief time. If an effect causes a card to be revealed, it remains revealed for as long as necessary to complete the parts of the effect that card is relevant to. If the cost to cast a spell or activate an ability includes revealing a card, the card remains revealed from the time the spell or ability is announced until the time it leaves the stack.

Comment: "You have to show all the players which cards you chose to put in your hand."